# Filter output of posts (Rest API)

Tags: rest-api

I have some custom post types. I use register_post_meta to register meta fields  - with show_in_rest so the data can be accessed via the Rest API. I use prepare_callback to run a custom function to clean up the output - e.g to remove  tags.

I want to do the same for the post content - specifically the title. But I can't find an equivalent place to attach a callback.

I prefer to do the XSS filtering on the output rather than the input. At any event I can't use DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML because in places I want to save html tags.

How can I run a callback on the output via the Rest API of post and custom post data (not the meta data) so I can modify what is returned?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with the [`rest_prepare_<post type>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-post_type/)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Can you help me a bit further (maybe in an answer so I can upvote it if that suits you?). The function gets passed the response object, the post (WP_Post type) and the request object.  Is it sufficient just to return the modified response object? Why is it passed the Post object?

Comment: Yes, it should be sufficient, as long as you modified it properly. It's passed the Post object, as well as the request object, just so that we have a reference to the post/request object. And I think it's better if you write your own answer - one that specifically worked for you..